# Unlock location values for IK bones

Tags: animation, rigging

We have a rig set up that allows for stretchy IK limbs.
But we have a problem when exporting FBX files for those animations. When we try bring the fbx back into the scene, even though the locations of the bones are baked as they should be. The location is locked on all the bones that used to be part of the IK limb set up.
Is there a way to force Blender to unlock the location of these bones so that the fbx works when imported back into a scene?

Many thanks.